# Mysql trigger variable - find updating user

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I have table with fields:

1. id
2. data1
3. data2

next I want to set trigger that after update would write to log table changes:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `update_data` AFTER UPDATE on `data_table`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF (NEW.data1 != OLD.data1) THEN
       INSERT INTO data_tracking set old_value = OLD.data1, new_value = NEW.data1, field = "data1";
   END IF;
   -- similar for data2
END$$
```

I also want to record in data_tracking table user that made change, however this user is not part of original UPDATE that trigger the trigger. I it a way to let trigger know what user need to be recorded ?

This is PHP based web service with multiple registered users, that can make changes to record via website - those user i would like to add to trigger.

Answer (score 1):

As you want to use the user name that only is known to PHP, well, MySql cannot know which user triggered the change if this information is only available in PHP. This means you would at least have to pass the user in every update statement, either adding this as a column to all tables that need this kind of trigger, or do all the updates via stored procedures that get the user name as an additional parameter. Then you could get rid of all the triggers, as you would use stored procedures anyway that can do the logging as well as the updates.

Comment: Agree, it other know way to pass this user info, like SET variable when establish connection or other "hack"... ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `CURRENT_USER`, see the MySQL manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_current-user

Comment: Current user would hold value that PHP (in my case) is using to connect to DB, I do not want to create so many mysql users...